# Extract DateTime from the string

Tags: c#

I have a string below.

```
String s = "2014-12-19_16-09-19_test.10_A.txt";
```

what is the best way to extract the '2014-12-19_16-09-19' from the string rather then use String.Split()?

I have tried with regex but only extract '2014-12-19'.

```
(\d+)[-.\/](\d+)[-.\/](\d+)
```

Comment: Is this the only format possible?

Comment: for the datetime, yes. @shree.pat18

Comment: Because the date and time format are fixed and always occupy the same position and the same number of characters, why don't you use substring method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}");
```

Assumption: The string to be searched for is in the format "2014-12-19_16-09-19" only. If the separators are different, or if number of digits is variable, the regex has to be updated accordingly.

Alternatively, if the position of the underscores is always fixed, you could avoid regexes altogether. You can split by underscore and then join back the first and second elements of the split array, like so:

```
var v = s.Split('_');
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("_", new string[] {v[0],v[1]}));
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/KYYRQ2279)

Answer (score 4):

I would use the following method:

```
const string format = "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss";

String s = "2014-12-19_16-09-19_test.10_A.txt";

var dateTimeSubstring = s.Substring(0, format.Length);

var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeSubstring, format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

With this code, you will get a 'dt' variable of type DateTime, with all functionality, like dt.Year, dt.Month, etc

Comment: Since `format` is a constant string, you could just pass in it's length as a hard coded value instead of computing it.

Answer (score 3):

I find this code much more readable than regex.

```
String s = "2014-12-19_16-09-19_test.10_A.txt";      
string date = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("_", s.IndexOf("_") + 1));
```

It extracts the string up until the second underscore, which I assume is going to be a common theme in these filenames.

In this case you'll get the date string which then you can cast to datetime.

Comment: This will only extract '2014-12-19' while OP wants '2014-12-19_16-09-19'

Comment: actually no, it returns "2014-12-19_16-09-19" and he could split it at the "_" char then convert to datetime.